# Pointing multiple Route53 subdomains to a single S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a Route53 subdomain (test.site.co.uk) and I want to be able to point it at a main S3 bucket (testing.uat.co.uk). I will also have more subdomains soon needing to do the same thing.

I cannot set the Alias Target to the S3 bucket because it is a different name which it needs to be. I am changing the content displayed on the bucket's site to respond to the targetted URL. For this reason, I need to keep the URL because I have also tried to redirect a bucket of the same name to the domain of the main bucket but that changes the URL.

Is there any way around this where I can keep the targeted domain?

Answer (score 3):

The ideal approach to do is using Amazon CloudFront with Lambda@Edge. In CloudFront, you can set multiple Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) and with Lambda@Edge you can process the request to display different content:

```
 import json

 def lambda_handler(event, context):
     request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']
     headers = request['headers']

     if request['domainName'] == 'example1.com':
         # Do this 1
     elif request['domainName'] == 'example2.com':
         # Do this 2
     else:
         # Do this else
```

Comment: any example codebase for this? can you elaborate on different content bit please? what content could vary?

Comment: I have a very similar question if you could care to look please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605178/dynamically-create-new-subdomains-and-point-to-a-cloud-front-distribution-pointi