# Dynamically create new subdomains and point to a cloud front distribution pointing to an s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, subdomain, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

S3 Bucket in question will have my website files that will be served by a CloudFront distribution. As new customers sign up (It is a multi-tenant serverless application), new subdomains will be created dynamically (not * wild card operator as we wish to serve only valid subdomains associated to customers or redirect to root domain). The website is being served from the same CloudFront distribution/ S3 bucket.

How can I dynamically create new subdomains and point to a cloud front distribution pointing to an s3 bucket?

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: What does it mean "dynamically"? Using CloudFormation?

Comment: As a new customer signs up in the application, a new subdomain fo the customer should be created @Marcin